# Ionic 2 foreground or background

Tags: ionic2

I am an `ionic2` beginner.

I need check my app is foreground or background currently running.

I refer this https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/local-notifications/

I need notification received only at app is run on background.

Comment: We need more information, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks.Kindly check it.I update my code.can u help me..

Answer (score 0):

You can use pause and resume [Cordova events](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#pause).
Subscribe your functions to them (taken from the link) :

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
function onPause() {
// Handle the pause event
}
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

function onResume() {
// Handle the resume event
}
```

Comment: Thanks.I used this Events.But this function called repeated in rootpage.How can i fix this pblm..

Comment: can you be more specific?